# “How to fix ‘Auto-regeneration infinine loop’ in Jekyll”

Tags: jekyll, infinite-loop

How to fix ‘Auto-regeneration infinine loop’ error in Jekyll?

1. Installed newest version: Ruby, Gem.
2. Created new project's => Same error.

```
Regenerating: 7 file(s) changed at 2019-08-15 21:25:54
                    _site/404.html
                    _site/about/index.html
                    _site/index.html
                    _site/assets/main.css
                    _site/feed.xml
                    _sg. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.g. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.ite/2019/08/15/Testseite.html
                    _site/jekyll/update/2019/08/15/welcome-to-jekyll.html
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    ...done in 0.1852189 seconds.
```

This output came over and over again.

Comment: **This is not an error message**. This the normal jekyll output for a 'bundle exec jekyll serve --' command. You can close this question or elaborate a little more about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out, the problem was a directory read-only story.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by commenting `gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.1", :platforms => [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]` in Gemfile.